# Constructing homotopy between maps

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, fundamental-groups

So we have the fundamental group $\pi_1 (X, x_0)$ with loops $f:I\rightarrow X $ and $e$ the constant loop. 
I’m trying to construct a homotopy between the concatenation $f •e $ and $f$.

I’m told and have verified that the homotopy $$F(s,t)= x_0 , 2s\leq t \text{ or } 2s-1\geq t $$ $$F(s,t)=f(2s-t) \text{ o/w } $$ works.

But I want to know how to come up with this because other parts of the proof that $(\pi _1(X,x_0 ), •)$ is a group depends on constructing homotopies.

[Here $I=[0,1] $].

Comment: Have you seen [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646034/4280)? I give a reference therein to a note I wrote that proves all the axioms for the homotopy group, one example of which is in that answer.

Comment: Thank you but the note isn’t loading when I click onto it.  Do you have another link perhaps?

Comment: I will suggest you to go through the section of fundamental groupoid in the book “ an introduction to algebraic topology “ by Rotman. There he explained how to choose the appropriate homotopies.

Comment: Thank you I’ve just had a look and I see these diagrams of an s-t plane. I have these diagrams in my notes and I’m just wondering how they know how to split the plane into the regions they do. That’s basically my whole problem.

Comment: The direct link to the note is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3646034/4280). Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: Thank you but this that link just take so me to the page where you state the homotopy but not how you originally constructed it.

Comment: So you mention there a link to a page where you go over all the parts of the proof that the fundamental group is a group.